Excel - Count 'non-blank' cells in a column based on an individual
I'm looking at trying to count the number of non-blank cells in a column, based on the name of the individual. I'll provide an example below.
I also want to be able to create a separate sheet with an 'overview' which will list all of the unique names in the column (in alphabetical order) and itemise the number of non-blank cells in one of three columns.
In this dataset, as an example, there would be two in 'Unit 1' for Tom Watts or as another example, there would be only one for Aarron Conroy in 'Unit 2'.
I hope that makes sense.
Thanks

COUNTIF, COUNT, IFBLANK and VLOOKUP!

Can you clarify what you want the output to be/look like? What formulas have you tried so far, and what is their return?

Here is one way of achieving the desired outcome using a LAMBDA() helper function called REDUCE() function:


• Formula used in cell F1
=REDUCE(A1:D1,SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A7)),LAMBDA(α,δ,VSTACK(α,
 HSTACK(δ,BYCOL(IFS((B2:D7<>"")*(A2:A7=δ),B2:D7),
 LAMBDA(Σ,@COUNT(Σ)))))))


The above formula is one single dynamic array formula, however, an easier method will be using COUNTIFS() :


• Enter in cell F2
=SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A7))


• Enter in cell F1
=A1:D1


• Enter in cell G2 and fill down and fill right!
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$F2,B$2:B$7,"<>")


Or, one another way to use BYCOL() and fill down, note that you would still need to apply the first two formula as in above:


=BYCOL(FILTER(B$2:D$7,$F2=A$2:A$7),LAMBDA(r,SUM(N(r<>""))))


One would need to change the cell reference and ranges accordingly as per their suit.

